# Python Popen and automatically continue to the next instruction

Tags: python, python-2.7, popen

I am trying to start and stop an in-memory database server from a python script for a certain experiment I'm working on. The issue that I am facing is that I'm not able to figure out how to continue to the next instruction automatically. The following code seems to work except as I said, it will wait for the server to return. I tried to search various solutions but none worked - including the ones mentioned here on stackoverflow.

```
pid = subprocess.Popen(r"/PATH_TO/server",shell=True,stdin=None,
                  stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True).pid
    # DO SOME MORE STUFF HERE
```

Comment: `stdout=/dev/null` that's a syntax error.

Comment: You may want to call Popen on a separate thread:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Sorry, I have modified it. and that one also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Cool! this one worked. Thanks all!

```
import os
import subprocess
DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, 'wb')
pid = subprocess.Popen(r"PATH_TO/server",stdin=DEVNULL,stdout=DEVNULL,
                      stderr=DEVNULL, close_fds=True).pid
# CONTINUE TO THE NEXT STUFF
```